# Woocommerce gateway error "unable to process order this gateway is offline"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, gateway

Some of my customers keep getting this error when attempting an "Offline Payment".  Strange thing is it only happens to customers from the northeast portion of the country.  Mainly Rhode Island and Maine.  I successfully receive orders through the same process from all over the country.  Any idea what may be causing this?  Much appreciated!